# What decides the calling order of OnCollisionEnter(other) in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie just starting learning Unity3d, and now I'm trying to make a simple cube collision game.

The method `OnCollisionEnter(other)` confused me. I want two different cubes to collide and update their behavior based on the other's state sequentially. But I can't decide the calling order of `OnCollisionEnter(other)` of each cube.

Some articles told me the order is decided by the hierarchy of project, but when I changed the order of two cubes in the hierarchy window, the calling order didn't change. I guess this method is sync, so how to know the correct calling order to avoid incorrect `other` state?

Edit:

These are scripts I use for two cubes, one as obstacle and one as mover:

Obstacle:

```cs
public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start() {
        this.tag = "Unhitted";
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
        Debug.Log("Obstacle has collision.");
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Mover" && this.tag == "Unhitted")
        {
            this.tag = "Hitted";
        }
    }
}
```

Mover:

```cs
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int hits = 0;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
        Debug.Log("Mover has collision.");
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Unhitted")
        {
            Debug.Log($"The mover has had {++hits} times collision");
        }
    }
}
```

I found always mover's `OnCollisionEnter` is called first. But I don't know whether this depends on different computer or inner mechanism of Unity. Because if obstacle's `OnCollisionEnter` is called first, the result will be wrong.

Comment: I would rather rethink the logic of your code instead of rely on execution order

Comment: @Cid sry I add my code and pls teach me some..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* always change the order of event calls between certain types via the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html).

However, most of the time I'd claim whenever you need to do this, it's due to a design flaw.

---

What I would rather do in your case would be

- Decide which of your scripts shall be the responsible actor. It uses the other script to tell it what to do.

In your case I see two main options

1. Either only `Mover` is the actor and checks for collision, checks for the `Obstacle` component and checks condition. Then it tells the `Obstacle` to get set to `Hitted`. `Obstacle` is only a reactor here.
2. Or `Obstacle` is the actor and checks for the collision, checks if it was already hit, check for the `Mover` component. Then it tells the `Mover` to increase the hit counter. `Mover` is only a reactor here.

With which one you want to go depends on personal preferences and the design of the rest of your project.

---

For the option 1

Obstacle:

```csharp
// Does nothing on its own but holding and providing the state
public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I would use an enum (or even bool) State instead of tags!
    public enum State
    {
        Unhitted,
        Hitted
    }

    public State state;
}
```

Mover:

```csharp
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int hits = 0;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Mover has collision.");
        if (other.TryGetComponent<Obstacle>(out var obstacle) && obstacle.state == Obstacle.State.Unhitted)
        {
            Debug.Log($"The mover has had {++hits} times collision", this);
            obstacle.state = Obstacle.State.Hitted;
        }
    }
}
```

---

For option 2

Obstacle:

```csharp
public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Just as an example this time I use the bool instead of the enum 
    // again how exactly you check the state is up to you
    // but in my eyes tags is not the best solution
    [SerializeField] private bool hitted;

    private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
    {
        if(!hitted && other.TryGetComponent<Mover>(out var mover))
        {
            Debug.Log($"The mover has had {++mover.hits} times collision", this);

            hitted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Mover:

```csharp
// Mover does nothing itself but holding and providing the hit counter
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hits = 0;
}
```

---

In both solutions of course you can implement better encapsulation where needed and e.g. make the fields readonly and only set them via methods etc but I hope the idea is clear and gives you a good start point.

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer is very clear and helpful